# JSQMessagesViewController in a custom view

Tags: ios, xcode, chat, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm trying to create a Chat system in my custom `UIViewcontroller`. I want to know if somebody have an idea to do that with `JSQMessagesViewController`. I want to add an `JSQMessagesView` in a view of my VC.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have here all you need to do is subclass the `JSQMessagesView` and make sure your messages conform to the `JSQMessageModel`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add a container view on storyboard and link that container view to a viewController that subclass JSQMessagesView.
That way you can set the container view to the size or position you want and the chat will only load inside that container.

Note: If you need to pass some variables to the chat view or you need to do some task before it is initialize override prepareForSegue.

If you have doubts please let me know I will explain it clearly, but I think that you will get the idea :D